# how to disable SSH login with password for some users?

Tags: linux, ssh, password, login

On Linux (Debian Squeeze) I would like to disable SSH login using password to some users (selected group or all users except root). But I do not want to disable login using certificate for them.

**edit:** thanks a lot for detailed answer! For some reason this does not work on my server:

```
Match User !root
PasswordAuthentication no
```

...but can be easily replaced by

```
PasswordAuthentication no
Match User root
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of your indentation?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that those lines under match should be at the end of the file

Comment: !root also doesn't work for me. The second approach did the trick.

Comment: I've seen cases where `Match User "!root,*"` did the job.

Comment: Apropos of nothing, allowing password authentication for `root` is a very bad idea security-wise.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Try `Match` in `sshd_config`:

```
Match User user1,user2,user3,user4
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Or by group:

```
Match Group users
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Or, as mentioned in the comment, by negation:

```
Match User !root
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Note that match is effective ["until either another Match line or the end of the file."](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) (the indentation isn't significant)

Comment: prefer `Match user !root` for this case

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about the Match syntax. One suggestion I would make, though, is if this is a public facing server, I wouldn't allow root login through SSH at all. Probably not a huge deal if it's Internal though..

Comment: _I wouldn't allow root login through SSH at all_ - We use **strong** root password so this is not real security weakness.

Comment: Strong or not, it can be brute-forced.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff That's what a) strong passwords and b) denyhosts/fail2ban are for.

Comment: Also note: Put these lines to the **end** (!) of the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and reload the SSH config: `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload`

Comment: Quite important in order to avoid errors such as: `Directive XYZ is not allowed within a Match block`.

Comment: @ceejayoz In the context of SSH, I'd suggest that's what a key-based login is for. Usually root login is unavoidable for admins who don't have physical access to their servers, very common in smaller scale web applications.

Comment: @deed02392 You can consider a key to be a really, really strong password if you like.

Comment: It's so much stronger it's not in the same ball-park, that was my point. Password authentication should be disabled for root too and keys only allowed for logins.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, really strong passwords (no dict words, length >= 15 chars, mixed chars, etc.) cannot be brute forced over SSH (way too slow, would take a million years to crack).  If you have the /etc/shadow file and a beastly rainbow table then you *might* be able to, but even then probably not.  That being said, a really hard password usually gets written down...

Comment: I need "only sftp, no ssh", it will block also sftp?

Comment: @ceejayoz No matter how strong a password you choose, it will not give you the security of key based authentication. That's because the key validation actually providers an extra layer of defence against mitm attacks, which you will not get with a stronger password.

Comment: didn't work for me, ssh would not restart with the above block anywhere in the file

Comment: As per Trevor Hateley's answer, you'll probably need `Match all` on a new line afterwards, otherwise sshd will attempt to treat the remainder of the file as part of your block, and either refuse to restart with the Directive Foo is not allowed errors, or worse, start silently, but apply subsequent settings to the wrong people.

Comment: BTW nowadays this will not disable password authentication as long as you have "ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes". And unfortunately ChallengeResponseAuthentication cannot be included in a "Match" block.

Answer (score 36):

`Match` in `sshd_config` works well. You should use `Match all` to end the match block if you're using openssh 6.5p1 or above. Example:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
Match User root
PasswordAuthentication yes
Match all
```

Comment: It didn't work for me...

Comment: "Match all" did the trick. Thank you. Without "Match all" sshd fails to start.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It is working now after putting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` instead of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d`.

Comment: "Match all" made it work for me. Without "Match all" in the end, the ssh and sshd services were failing to restart.

Answer (score 3):

Due to some security reason, you may require to block certain user SSH access to Linux box.

Edit the sshd_config file, the location will sometimes be different depending on Linux distribution, but it’s usually in /etc/ssh/.

Open the file up while logged on as root:

```
# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Insert a line to end of the config file:-

```
DenyUsers username1 username2 username3 username4
```

Save it and restart SSH services. Basically username1, username2, username3 & username4 SSH login is disallowed.

Run below command to restart the same:-

```
# systemctl restart sshd
```

The requirement has been done. Please take the ssh from that users and your will get error "Access Denied"

Comment: The question was about disabling password login (but keeping login with key authentication).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways that you can do this - first, you could concievably run a second sshd daemon on a different port with different config - its a bit of a hack, but with some chroot work it should work just fine.

Also, you could allow password authentication, but lock the passwords
for all but the one user. The users with locked passwords will still be
able to authenticate with public keys.

Answer (score 0):

The order of config-statements counts ... my solution to the file

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User <username> 
PasswordAuthentication yes
Match User all
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: See [formatting help](/help/formatting) to learn how to add formatting to your posts.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply go to /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and add a line 
To allow --> AllowUsers user1 
To Deny ---> DenyUsers  user2

we can allow/deny login for a particular set of hosts using the hosts.allow or hosts.deny files located in /etc folder