# SSH Allow Password For One User, Rest Only Allow Public Keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Is it possible with ssh to allow passwords from a certain user, but deny using passwords for everybody else?

Basically I want to allow password auth for user `justin` but everybody else must use public keys.

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Seems to be global though, no way to specify by user.

Comment: Look at the sshd_config man page, and look at the section for the Match directive.

Comment: Why? If you're the administrator of the server, your account ought to be protected just as much as the rest of the users, if not more so.

Comment: This question [how to disable SSH login with password for some users?](http://serverfault.com/questions/285800/how-to-disable-ssh-login-with-password-for-some-users) has the answer you want.

Comment: When I try and use the match syntax, Match User justin
PasswordAuthentication yes I am getting Bad configuration option: Match when I restart sshd.

Comment: Wow, how old is your SSH?

Comment: CentOS 5.6, looks to be: OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008. There inst an update in yum.

Comment: The changelog (http://www.openssh.org/txt/release-4.4) seems to indicate that this is a 4.4 and above feature.

Comment: So I do have to build openssh from source, or is there a yum repo I can add, and do yum update?

Answer (score 115):

Necromancing, but adding the following to your sshd_config should do the trick:

```
Match User <username>
PasswordAuthentication yes
Match all
```

Note that match is effective "[until either another Match line or the end of the file.](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)" (The indentation isn't significant.)

Comment: You can also do a `Match Group <groupname>` if you want to use a common group to manage the password-allowed users ([see this link](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/18038/52494)). Remember to restart ssh, which you can do in Ubuntu with `sudo service ssh restart`. :)