# Restrict password based SSH access per user but allow key authentication

Tags: linux, ssh

Is it possible to disable PASSWORD SSH access to user but to allow Key authentication on a per user basis ?
I mean, I have a userA whom I don't want to give Password based access BUT I wan't him to only use key authentication to access the server(s).
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable SSH login with password for some users?](http://serverfault.com/questions/285800/how-to-disable-ssh-login-with-password-for-some-users)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can add "Match" sections to match on particular users or groups at the bottom of sshd_config, like:

```
Match user stew
PasswordAuthentication no
```

or

```
Match group dumbusers
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: I would avoid indenting as it suggests that only the indented lines are affected by `Match` when in reality, all configuration is affected until the next `Match` directive. Could be confusing to someone not familiar with with the syntax.

Comment: @MichaelMior is there a way to "EndMatch"?

Comment: @NickT `Match` works up until the next `Match` or `Host` keyword. You could just use `Match user *`.

Comment: @MichaelMior Does this mean that if you use `Match user ZaQwEdCxS`, you could render a set of configuration lines usable by nobody, temporarily or permanently?

Comment: It would mean that all configuration lines after that would only apply to users named `ZaQwEdCxS`. If you have a different question though, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Another way for formatting is to indent, but put a `Match all` at the bottom of the block so the rest of the file is back to being global.

Answer (score 4):

Just lock the passwords of the users you don't want to log in with passwords:

```
usermod -L <user>
```

Then, place a valid public key in their `.ssh/authorized_keys` file and they will be only able to log in with the corresponding private key, but not with a password.

**Note:** This will break sudo unless the user has NOPASSWD: in their visudo entry

Comment: That also will break sudo. Perhaps not an issue in this case, but it bears mention.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Some OpenSSH setups (e.g. i think Ubuntu 14.04 in default config) do not let locked users in, not even via authorized_keys

Comment: @NilsToedtmann can you cite a source for verification? This would be very important to note in the answer, as well, if so.

Answer (score -3):

you should look into

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I think what you're looking for is

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

change it to no and don't forget to restart sshd

Comment: I'm aware of this - this is a GLOBAL settings though - I want more granular option - that's why I said "per-user basis" - I want this only for some users (used for innercluster communication between the servers in the cluster) - not for all users

Comment: oh right, i'm sorry i didn't read it correctly then what @stew recommended is a way to go