# Is it possible to disable ssh password authentication for own user without root access?

Tags: ssh, debian, public-key

I would like to disable ssh password authentication for my user account on a server where I don't have root priviledges, so that I can only log in via publickey authentication.

Everything I found on the topic involved changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which I can't do obviously.

Is this possible at all?

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/a/387130/205986) answer to a similar question, but it's not clear to me whether it does what I want without side effects. And whether I can do it without `sudo`.

Comment: If you don't have write access to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, this is a Super User question.

Comment: A decent alternative, which does not require root privileges, is to use a very strong password on your account.

Comment: @EsaJokinen If it's a unix question, it'll be better off at [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: If I knew how to get this migrated, I would migrate it to unix/linux... just posted it here because all the other answers I found dealing with similar problems were here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

Apparently, the solution is to modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config by adding a block like this:

```
Match user myuser
PasswordAuthentication no
```

This obviously requires root privilege.

The linked answer in your question uses `usermod` to lock the user password. This also requires root privilege.

Modifying SSH client user-specific config file `~/.ssh/config` does not help in your case. This is simply because this file will be applied when connecting from your box and not when receiving SSH connections (client side!).